# Vert.x: Multiple JWTAuthHandler in one ChainAuthHandler

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, vert.x

I want to use two different JWTAuthHandler, each with a unique RS256 public key.
That is cause I get JWTs from two different sources.

A ChainAuthHandler should be the appropriate way to combine these two JWTAuthHandler.
However, it is not working...

The problem:

- When iterating over all appended handlers, the ChainAuthHandler only
  checks whether parseCredentials() results in an error.
- Since the JWTAuthHandler in parseCredentials() only look for an
  "Authorization"-Header, no error occurs.
- The exception is thrown way later in JWTAuthProviderImpl.authenticate().

Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

JWT is an authorization mechanism, not authentication. If you user has a token this handler cannot confirm the user is who it claims to be. As there's no state, the token is only used to assert if the user is authorized for a specific role. So you can only perform `isAuthorized()` calls.